# Multiply xarray variables with a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have an `xarray.DataArray`:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'eofs' (mode: 3, lat: 41, lon: 109)>
array([[[ 0.0436546 ,  0.04423243,  0.04479113, ...,  0.02626665,
          0.0257012 ,  0.02513798],
        [ 0.04490738,  0.04549405,  0.04606867, ...,  0.02734869,
          0.026775  ,  0.02619634],
        [ 0.04613635,  0.04672573,  0.0473114 , ...,  0.02844015,
          0.02785003,  0.02725326],
        ...,
        [ 0.05721894,  0.05787764,  0.05852705, ...,  0.0474642 ,
          0.04676448,  0.04606556],
        [ 0.05649778,  0.05714934,  0.05779039, ...,  0.04714761,
          0.04645796,  0.04576794],
        [ 0.05573076,  0.05637409,  0.05700592, ...,  0.04678733,
          0.04610882,  0.04542908]],
]]])
Coordinates:
  * mode     (mode) int32 0 1 2
  * lat      (lat) float64 50.0 50.25 50.5 50.75 51.0 ... 59.25 59.5 59.75 60.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 -2.0 -1.75 -1.5 -1.25 -1.0 ... 24.25 24.5 24.75 25.0
```

and I want ro multiply each mode with an element of the array `array([68.8005905 , 17.8959575 ,  8.46729004])`. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: great question! I clarified that you want to multiply by a numpy array in your question title and added the numpy tag to help others with similar questions find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what xarray is intended to help with you're on the right track!

Unlike numpy, which relies on *dimension order* and *positional indices* to align arrays, xarray relies on *dimension names* and *coordinate labels*. So the key to making sure xarray knows how to align your `np.array` with your `xr.DataArray` is to assign the appropriate dimension names and coordinates to the array.

In this case:

```py
multiplier = xr.DataArray(
    [68.8005905 , 17.8959575 ,  8.46729004],
    dims=['mode'],
    coords=[[0, 1, 2]],
)
```

Now you can simply multiply them! Assuming your DataArray is called `da`:

```py
# these will be aligned automatically
da * multiplier
```

See the xarray docs on [computation: automatic alignment](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment) for more on this topic.

Alternatively, you can still do this operation in numpy by accessing the [`DataArray.data`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.data.html) property:

```py
da.data = da.data * np.array([68.8005905 , 17.8959575 ,  8.46729004]).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

When using direct array manipulation like this, normal numpy broadcasting rules apply. This will in almost all cases be faster than using xarray's automatic alignment, but there are downsides. You cannot assign the result to the same DataArray's data attribute if you change the dimensions, and be careful not to re-order the values - *assigning directly to `.data` like this is playing with fire and removes xarray's ability to ensure data alignment for you* - you've been warned! Note that the result of an operation using `da.data` will be a numpy array (or whatever array backend is in use, e.g. a dask array), so if you do want to dip into numpy and then come back to xarray, you can always just create a new DataArray and assign the dimensions and coordinates using the [DataArray constructor](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#creating-a-dataarray) as I did above.